# Creating a List of a List in heavily repeated python functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm rather new to python especially when it comes to class attributes and how they work. I've come across this problem where I have a function 'builddata' which outputs a list(Coarsegraining) of a few ints, and sends this to another function 'coarse_grain'.

Over the coarse of the script, these functions are called hundreds of times with CoarseGraining being different every time. What I want to do, is either:

a) Every time CoarseGraining reaches 'coarse_grain' it use that instance, but also saves it to a larger list, which after several repetitions of the function, will contain however many of these different CoarseGraining configurations there are, which can then be used later.

b) Define this process elsewhere, where CoarseGraining is instead sent to 2 functions, where it goes through its usual process in one, but then also is configured into this so called list of a list, which can then be used.

I should also mention, all these functions are defined within the same class 'MultiFitter'. I'd prefer method a) for simplicity reasons, but any possible solutions would be great. Below is a small excerpt of what i'm talking about.

Cheers

```
class MultiFitter(object):

  def __init__(
    self, models, mopt=None, ratio=False, fast=True, extend=False,
        fitname=None, wavg_svdcut=None, **fitterargs
    ):
    super(MultiFitter, self).__init__()
    models = [models] if isinstance(models, MultiFitterModel) else models
    self.models = models
    self.fit = None         # last fit
    self.ratio = ratio
    self.mopt = mopt
    self.fast = fast
    self.extend = extend
    self.wavg_svdcut = wavg_svdcut       
    self.fitterargs = fitterargs        
    self.fitname = (
        fitname if fitname is not None else
        lambda x : x
        )

  def builddata(self, data=None, pdata=None, prior=None, mf=None):        
    if mf is None:
        mf = self._get_mf()
        mf['flatmodels'] = self.flatten_models(mf['models'])
    if pdata is None:
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError('no data or pdata')
        pdata = gvar.BufferDict()
        for m in mf['flatmodels']:

            M = m.builddata(data)
            CoarseGraining = []
            c1 = 1
            c2 = 0
            for i in range(1, M.shape[0]):                  
                z = gvar.evalcorr([M[c2],M[i]])
                corrValue = z[1][0]                
                if corrValue >= 0.7:
                    c1 = c1 + 1                                              
                    if i == M.shape[0]-1:                            
                        CoarseGraining.append(int(c1))                    
                else:
                    CoarseGraining.append(int(c1))                        
                    c2 = c2 + c1
                    c1 = 1
                    if i == M.shape[0]-1:                            
                        CoarseGraining.append(int(1))            
            pdata[m.datatag] = (
                m.builddata(data) if m.ncg <= 1 else                    
                MultiFitter.coarse_grain(m.builddata(data), CoarseGraining)
                )

  @staticmethod
  def coarse_grain(G, CoarseGraining):

    G = numpy.asarray(G)             
    D = []        
    counter = 0

    for i, ncg in enumerate(CoarseGraining):            
        D.append(str(numpy.sum(G[..., counter:counter + ncg], axis=-1) / ncg))       
        counter = counter + ncg

    D = numpy.asarray(D)
    print(array, 'IS THIS IT???')
    print(D ,'\n')
    #return numpy.transpose([G])
    return G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make `coarse_grain` a regular method of `class MultiFitter` and instantiate `full_list` in your class `__init__`. Then append to the list in your `coarse_grain` method.

You can then access your list of lists via `self.full_list`.

```
def __init__(...):
    self.full_list = []

def coarse_grain(self, G, CoarseGraining):

    G = numpy.asarray(G)             
    D = []        
    counter = 0

    for i, ncg in enumerate(CoarseGraining):            
        D.append(str(numpy.sum(G[..., counter:counter + ncg], axis=-1) / ncg))       
        counter = counter + ncg

    D = numpy.asarray(D)

    self.full_list.append(D)    

    return G
```